# How to discover if dpkg --configure -a would do anything if invoked?

Tags: apt, dpkg

Say I've got a few hundred Ubuntu machines and about half of 'em have a semi-complete kernel installed and rebooting them is a tremulous terror, I want to audit all my machines and I think that if I run `dpkg --configure -a` I'll get some output telling me what the last mucked up thing on the system was.

However, I don't want to run anything, I just want to know which machines are mucked up.  What command can tell me what problems I might have with apt-get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `dpkg` man page:

```
-C, --audit
          Searches for packages that have been installed only partially on 
          your system. dpkg will suggest what to do with them to get them working.
```